# WPF: Problem with ItemsControl datatemplate as a user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, itemscontrol

This works fine:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

But, I want to make use of a User Control in place of the stack panel with two TextBlocks using something like:

```
  <DataTemplate>
    <jasControls:NameView/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

But, with this and a million other syntaxes, the NameView shows nothing, yet it works fine in a separate test, outside the ItemsControl, with explicitly set (dependency) property - e.g.

```
  <jasControls:NameView FName="{Binding Path=Person.FirstName}"  />
```

I can find hardly any examples of this anywhere, and need to know how to specify the properties of the user control - or how can the user control 'receive' the individual item type (a Person)? What syntax to use? Do I need to specify the datatype? Is ItemsControl causing a problem or should any similar control do e.g. ListBox? Can I design it so that the user control gets an entire Person object? What dependency properties do I need in the user control? In short, how to get data into the user control?! The actual business types involved will be a bit more complicated involving some logic in the user control, hence my desire to use a user control.

ANY direction on this will be very gratefully received - TIA

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your `Persons` collection has many `Person` objects in it, the `DataContext` property of your `NameView` control will automatically be set to the `Person` object.

You wouldn't need any dependency properties to achieve this feat.  Your NameView usercontrol would simply be:

```
<UserControl ...>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You should have no codebehind to get this information to display.

From there, you should be able to access the Person object from the DataContext property:

```
Person person = this.DataContext as Person;
```

Comment: Remarkably (to me!) that does work! I had been using a 'mini view model' and dependency properties in the UC. I still don't know why a DP of type Person does not work...? Anyway, the actual context is more complex, and one property I need to 'pass in' is the name of a control type using which I will display an appropriate editing control. I can see the datacontext as you said, but now need to work out when I can dynamically add the control within the user control. Another questions remains - when _would_ you need dependency properties in this situation? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You *could* create a dependency property of type Person on your usercontrol and set its value to be {Binding}.  If you really wanted to break out FName and LName, you could set them to FName="{Binding FirstName}", but you are probably not gaining much.